# Sh : file not found on alpine Docker image

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi3, alpine-linux

I installed Docker on my Raspberry Pi3.
I want to install the "registry" image. As I do not find it in ARM, I have built an AMR version.

I recompiled the binary from the git https://github.com/docker/distribution/

I get a functional binary:

```
# registry --version
src_docker/go/bin/registry github.com/docker/distribution v2.6.0+unknown
```

Then I left the git https://github.com/docker/distribution-library-image to customize the Dockerfile.

```
FROM arm32v6/alpine:3.5

RUN set -ex \
   && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates apache2-utils

COPY ./registry/registry /bin/registry
COPY ./registry/config-example.yml /etc/docker/registry/config.yml

VOLUME ["/var/lib/registry"]
EXPOSE 5000

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["/etc/docker/registry/config.yml"]
```

I have of course to replace the "registry / registry" by the binary that I compiled.

I build image :

```
docker build . -t ikise_arm/registry
```

But when I execute the image it does not find the binary

```
# docker run -ti ikise_arm/registry:latest
/entrypoint.sh: exec: line 10: registry: not found
```

If I disable the ENTRYPOINT and explore the files I find the biary but impossible to execute

```
# docker run -ti ikise_arm/registry:latest
/ # ls -al /bin/r*
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar  2 20:19 /bin/reformime -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      19940588 Jun 14 12:27 /bin/registry
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar  2 20:19 /bin/rev -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar  2 20:19 /bin/rm -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar  2 20:19 /bin/rmdir -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar  2 20:19 /bin/run-parts -> /bin/busybox
/ # /bin/registry
sh: /bin/registry: not found
```

Do you have any idea where the problem may come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I adapted the image https://github.com/docker-library/golang/tree/master/1.8/alpine3.6
To compile the binary registry

(https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/78)